# Package conflict when trying to update a release apk of my app?

Tags: android

I just generated a release apk of an app I'm building, and I attempted to install it on my phone (where the previous release apk already is), but I'm getting a package conflict with the previous version. I'm using the same keystore as before (I've checked), and the password and the alias are also correct. I'm bewildered by why I'm getting this error, are there other reasons why I might get a package conflict?

I even restored my code to what it was last time I generated the release apk, and tried to make a new one and it still gave me a package conflict. Is it possible for a keystore file to stop working? I'm stumped.

Comment: Did you bump the version code?

Comment: Are you using Mac or Linux?

Comment: @Veritas I increased the version number.

Comment: @MidasLefko Windows

Comment: Is it a new computer? Or the same one that built the previous version?

Comment: @MidasLefko same one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I solved it but just in case someone else has this problem, I'm posting it here. The other version on my phone was the Beta one that I downloaded from my listing on the Play Store. For some reason, Beta was conflicting with the apk, even though there wasn't an issue with the signing. Once I removed myself from Beta the apk was fine, and everything worked perfectly after being uploaded to the Play store, both for Beta and normal production.
Don't know why this was an issue, but it was so... yeah.